# name Column "rownames" in output file

Tags: r

When I write a table in R, the rownames are printed as first column. However, the first column name (from the object) is automatically placed above the rownames, like this:

```
                 Object                           Output table:
       Sample1   Sample2   Sample3      Sample1  Sample2  Sample3:
Gene1     4        32         5           Gene1     4       32         5
Gene2     23       43         23          Gene2     3       43         23
Gene3     24       34         14          Gene3     4       34         14
```

I tried different ways to solve this, e.g.:

```
names <- c("GeneNr", names(DF))
names
# [1] "GeneNr"        "Sample1"      "Sample2"  "Sample3"
write.table(DF, file= "DF.txt"), sep = "\t", col.names = names)
```

but this does not work.

Does any know how to solve this?

Comment: try `DF$GeneNR <- rownames(DF)` to create the column, then when you write to file, use `write.table(..., row.names=FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

The simultaneous use of `row.names=T` and `col.names=NA` permits to correctly place your column names.

```
write.table(df, "df.txt", sep = "\t", row.names = T, quote = F, col.names = NA)
```